# How to clear a tkinter window Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, destroy

I have tried to clear some widgets (buttons) from a tkinter window in python by using `button.destroy()` but I have to use the button after so I have tried `button.pack_forget()`.
After using the forget method I have tried to use the button again by doing `button.pack()` but it's not working.
Why?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you are having.

Comment: What is *"it's not working"*?  The button does not show up? The button shows up in different place? Or other?

Comment: Seems that you are doing it right: when you want to remove the widget from the pack layout (=> making it disappear), you call `pack_forget()`; when you want to put it back, you call `pack()`. Just don't destroy the widget; then there will be nothing to put back.